# Load DirectoryInfo Content into textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem while following this Microsoft Tutorial (Step 2):
[Step 2: Fixing the Workflow for Unauthorized, Authenticated Users](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/user-based-authorization-cs)

I have a complete list of files in my ROOT, so when I click "EDIT" in my gridview, the content of the file should be displayed in the Textbox.
So let's say I click EDIT to Default.aspx, then the content/code in Default.aspx should be displayed.

**.ASPX:**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="FileContents" runat="server" Rows="10" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="95%"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:GridView ID="FilesGrid" DataKeyNames="Name" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField SelectText="View" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Length" DataFormatString="{0:N0}" HeaderText="Size in Bytes"
                HtmlEncode="False" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**.ASPX.CS:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string appPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(appPath);

            FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles();

            FilesGrid.DataSource = files;
            FilesGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void FilesGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open the file and display it
        string fullFileName = FilesGrid.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(fullFileName);
        FileContents.Text = contents;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
<asp:GridView ID="FilesGrid" DataKeyNames="Name" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

Is missing `onselectedindexchanged`

```
<asp:GridView ID="FilesGrid" DataKeyNames="Name" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FilesGrid_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Answer (score 0):

can you change this code

```
    protected void FilesGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open the file and display it
        string fullFileName = FilesGrid.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(fullFileName);
        FileContents.Text = contents;
    }
```

to read like this

```
    protected void FilesGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open the file and display it
        string fullFileName = FilesGrid.SelectedValue.ToString();
        List<string> contents = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(fullFileName));
        FileContents.Text = contents.ToString();
    }
```

*** also make sure that fullFileName has the Fully Qualified FilePath+FileName

Comment: I just inserted the code you provided, but it didn't change help. I am not sure what you mean by "fullFileName has the Fully Qualified FilePath+FileName", could you explain?:)

Comment: the file that you are trying to read from.. does it have a filePath + file name for example "c:\\mypath\\myfilename.txt for example..? when you say doesn't work.. which line in your code is it truly failing at ...? have you used the debugger to step thru the code I would also refactor the code to utilize some Try catche {}

Comment: Honestly, I don't know buddy. I have just followed the tutorial and it doesn't say anything about that. I'm not sure if this helps but currently I can see all my files like in this image: [link](http://www.sp34k.com/etc/stackoverflow/contentview.jpg)

Comment: back to my other question then.. where is it actually erroring out.. are you able to debug this and report on the exact line where the error is being thrown..?

Comment: Give me some time buddy, I'm new to all this so I gotta figure out how to debug it so I can give you the needed informations.

Comment: Click F9 on the line you want to break at .. and Click F10 to step